# XML split by specific line

Tags: xml

Hello I've got one long xml file and I need to split it into a few (about 367) small files. Do you know any program which I can use to split this file by lines?

```
...
>0.00</P_60
></PozycjeSzczegolowe
><Pouczenie
>Za uchybienie przewidziana w Kodeksie karnym skarbowym.</Pouczenie
></Deklaracja>
<!--END-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
```

I need a feed of the new files began

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and end

```
<!--END-->
```

(or any other phrase what i use in comment)

Comment: Which language you want to use? does it matter, or any would be OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over a input file line by line, and on each occasion `<!--END-->` appears create new output file.

In Python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

sep = "<!--END-->"

i = 0
outfile = open( "output"+str(i)+".xml", "w" )

for aLine in open( "input.xml", "r" ):
  if  aLine.strip() == sep:
    outfile.close()
    i += 1
    outfile = open( "output"+str(i)+".xml", "w" )
  else:
    print( aLine, file=outfile, end="" )
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate over `bigfile.xml` and start a new file when "`<?xml ...`" appears

```
 csplit --prefix="output" -n 3  bigfile.xml '/^<?xml/' "{*}"
```

If `bigfile.xml` starts with "`<?xml ...`", you can remove `output000` (empty file)